# How can i find Tomcat install location on Azure Linux VM (centos)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, tomcat8, azure-virtual-machine

I have installed (created a new web app) a new Tomcat 8 web server using "App Services", and i'm able to also access the default page (screenshots below). I'm not able to find tomcat's install location/files on the VM (Azure Linux VM - CentOS 7.4)?

I tried to run the below command in cloud shell, but cannot locate it.

```
find / -name "tomcat"
```

Screenshots:

[image: Tomcat 8 setup using App Services]

[image: Tomcat's default homepage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fistly, you run your app on a Windows host not a Linux host, so you could not use command `find / -name "tomcat"`. More information about this see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-overview).

Secondly, you need login Kudu console to check your web app files. The url is `http://<yoursite>.scm.azurewebsites.net`. On your scenario, the url is `http://suren-tomcat8.scm.azurewebsites.net`.

[image]

Comment: Your web app is not running on Cloud Shell, so, you could not find files on cloud shell.

Comment: thanks for the comments but @shengbao-shui-msft . But i'm confused. I can see Tomcat's files in Kudu but why can we not use a linux host? And i was assuming i can control the VM and it's files through CloudShell, like we generally do or other cloud vm's. Will have to do some reading!

Comment: You are right. On seeing carefully, i've setup tomcat using App Services. It shows the Os on which Tomcat was deployed is "Windows Server 2016", and the url to kudu you've sent makes sense.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more future help.